# what is the purpose of having function exec() in Hook.php in prestashop

Tags: php, function, e-commerce, smarty, prestashop

In the `Header.tpl` file there is a hook `{$HOOK_TOP}` which contains all the header part including menu, search etc... You can check that in this URL

In the `FrontController` it shows... `'HOOK_TOP' => Hook::exec('displayTop')`,
it means in the Hook page there is a function called `exec()`. But I cannot understand the code properly in the `exec()` call.

It tells it *Execute modules for specified hook*. When I searched for "*displayTop*" I got a module name called `blocktopmenu.php`.

Execution only goes through 2 functions:

```
    public function hookDisplayTop($param)
    {
        $this->user_groups =  ($this->context->customer->isLogged() ? $this->context->customer->getGroups() : array(Configuration::get('PS_UNIDENTIFIED_GROUP')));
        $this->page_name = Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController();
        if (!$this->isCached('blocktopmenu.tpl', $this->getCacheId()))
        {
            $this->makeMenu();
            $this->smarty->assign('MENU_SEARCH', Configuration::get('MOD_BLOCKTOPMENU_SEARCH'));
            $this->smarty->assign('MENU', $this->_menu);
            $this->smarty->assign('this_path', $this->_path);
        }

        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'js/hoverIntent.js');
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'js/superfish-modified.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/superfish-modified.css');

        $html = $this->display(__FILE__, 'blocktopmenu.tpl', $this->getCacheId());
        //print_r($html);//exit;
        return $html;
    }
```

and

```
protected function getCacheId($name = null)
{//echo"asdasdsad";exit;
    parent::getCacheId($name);
    $page_name = in_array($this->page_name, array('category', 'supplier', 'manufacturer', 'cms', 'product')) ? $this->page_name : 'index';
    return 'blocktopmenu|'.(int)Tools::usingSecureMode().'|'.$page_name.'|'.(int)$this->context->shop->id.'|'.implode(', ',$this->user_groups).'|'.(int)$this->context->language->id.'|'.(int)Tools::getValue('id_category').'|'.(int)Tools::getValue('id_manufacturer').'|'.(int)Tools::getValue('id_supplier').'|'.(int)Tools::getValue('id_cms').'|'.(int)Tools::getValue('id_product');
}
```

But this public function `hookDisplayTop($param)` never gets called in the whole folder anywhere. I searched it but never found it in any file.

The `exec()` function shows below

```
public static function exec($hook_name, $hook_args = array(), $id_module = null, $array_return = false, $check_exceptions = true)
    {

        // Check arguments validity
        if (($id_module && !is_numeric($id_module)) || !Validate::isHookName($hook_name))
            throw new PrestaShopException('Invalid id_module or hook_name');

        // If no modules associated to hook_name or recompatible hook name, we stop the function

        if (!$module_list = Hook::getHookModuleExecList($hook_name))
            return '';

        // Check if hook exists
        if (!$id_hook = Hook::getIdByName($hook_name))
            return false;

        // Store list of executed hooks on this page

        Hook::$executed_hooks[$id_hook] = $hook_name;
    //  print_r(Hook::$executed_hooks);exit;

        $live_edit = false;
        $context = Context::getContext();
        if (!isset($hook_args['cookie']) || !$hook_args['cookie'])
            $hook_args['cookie'] = $context->cookie;
        if (!isset($hook_args['cart']) || !$hook_args['cart'])
            $hook_args['cart'] = $context->cart;

        $retro_hook_name = Hook::getRetroHookName($hook_name);
//print_r($hook_name);exit;
        // Look on modules list
        $altern = 0;
        $output = '';
        foreach ($module_list as $array)
        {
            // Check errors
            if ($id_module && $id_module != $array['id_module'])
                continue;
            if (!($moduleInstance = Module::getInstanceByName($array['module'])))
                continue;

            // Check permissions
            if ($check_exceptions)
            {
                $exceptions = $moduleInstance->getExceptions($array['id_hook']);
                $controller = Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController();

                if (in_array($controller, $exceptions))
                    continue;

                //retro compat of controller names
                $matching_name = array(
                    'authentication' => 'auth',
                    'compare' => 'products-comparison',
                    );
                if (isset($matching_name[$controller]) && in_array($matching_name[$controller], $exceptions))
                    continue;
                if (Validate::isLoadedObject($context->employee) && !$moduleInstance->getPermission('view', $context->employee))
                    continue;
            }

            // Check which / if method is callable
            $hook_callable = is_callable(array($moduleInstance, 'hook'.$hook_name));
            $hook_retro_callable = is_callable(array($moduleInstance, 'hook'.$retro_hook_name));
            if (($hook_callable || $hook_retro_callable) && Module::preCall($moduleInstance->name))
            {
                $hook_args['altern'] = ++$altern;

                // Call hook method
                if ($hook_callable)
                    $display = $moduleInstance->{'hook'.$hook_name}($hook_args);
                else if ($hook_retro_callable)
                    $display = $moduleInstance->{'hook'.$retro_hook_name}($hook_args);
                // Live edit
                if (!$array_return && $array['live_edit'] && Tools::isSubmit('live_edit') && Tools::getValue('ad') && Tools::getValue('liveToken') == Tools::getAdminToken('AdminModulesPositions'.(int)Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminModulesPositions').(int)Tools::getValue('id_employee')))
                {
                    $live_edit = true;
                    $output .= self::wrapLiveEdit($display, $moduleInstance, $array['id_hook']);
                }
                else if ($array_return)
                    $output[] = $display;
                else
                    $output .= $display;
            }
        }
        if ($array_return)
            return $output;
        else
            return ($live_edit ? '<script type="text/javascript">hooks_list.push(\''.$hook_name.'\'); </script>
                <div id="'.$hook_name.'" class="dndHook" style="min-height:50px">' : '').$output.($live_edit ? '</div>' : '');// Return html string
    }
```

Comment: probably the hook method is being called dynamically in the exec() method you already mentioned. Just post the contents of the exec() method and I'll give it a shot

Comment: posted,,check @ThomasDavidPlat

Comment: @Xavier du Tertre ..can u tell me how to call only blocktopmenu module in prestashop...if i use displayTop hook it calls various other modules along with it..but i only want to call blocktopmenu..is it possible to create an object of Blocktopmenu class and access the hookDisplayTop() of that class..so that i can avoid other modules...i tried but its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not going to explain you the code line by line here, but i will explain you what the exec static member do.

When ever you call

```
Hook::exec("HookName");
```

It performs the following processes for you.

1) First it checks whether the hook is available or not? If it is not available return false;

2) Second it gets the module list for that hook from database. Also narrow down the list by exceptions for the modules for the hooks for the current page.

3) After it gets all the module(s) for the hook called for the current loaded (or called page) page, it calls the hooks function in the module. If you check modules for a specific hook you will find public function for that hook. Lets consider the Top hook. In modules you will have public functions like

```
public function hookTop // or public function hookDisplayTop for compatibility reasons
```

Please not that PS performs some other operations also there.

The above details are just giving you the idea that how hooks and modules work in PS. 
Also taking the above theory, i implemented the same operations in Codeigniter and Zend Framework for my own projects, and it works like a charm ;) .

If you still have any other questions, let me know and i will provide you as much details as i can.

Thank you

Comment: can u plz explain the frontend flow..it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Lines who call the HookDiplayTop are :

```
// Call hook method
if ($hook_callable)
$display = $moduleInstance->{'hook'.$hook_name}($hook_args);
else if ($hook_retro_callable)
$display = $moduleInstance->{'hook'.$retro_hook_name}($hook_args);
```

Comment: yes i agree with you..but can u explain how the module blocktopmenu gets called..is there any perticular flow of execution...and why public function hookDisplayTop($param) gets executed but never get called anywhere..how is it possible???

Comment: It has yet to be explained in the documentation, you're right. http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Diving+into+PrestaShop+Core+development#DivingintoPrestaShopCoredevelopment-TheFrontControllerclass
We're getting right on that, thanks to your feedback!